# How to return a zip file via AJAX that prompts for download?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core Action method that I want to return a zip file for downloading to the client and It looks like this:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateModel]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadCarousel([FromBody]CarouselViewModel model)
{
    File zip = await MediaService.DownloadAndZipCarousel(model.Images, BaseServerPath);
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=\"{zip.Name}.zip\"");
    return File(zip.Content, "application/zip", zip.Name);
}
```

zip.Content contains the byte array that I want to return as a zip so the client can download it. However, instead of getting a downloadble zip, the response looks like this:

[image]

This is my service doing the work, If that matters in any way:

```
public async Task<Models.Models.File> DownloadAndZipCarousel(IEnumerable<Image> images, string baseServerPath)
{
     HttpClient client     = CreateClient();
     var file              = new Models.Models.File();
     var random            = new Random();

     using (var archiveStream = new MemoryStream())
     using (var archive       = new ZipArchive(archiveStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
     {
          foreach (Image image in images)
          {
               ZipArchiveEntry archiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry($"Instagram{random.Next()}.jpg", CompressionLevel.Optimal);
               using (Stream entryStream = archiveEntry.Open())
               using (Stream contentStream = await client.GetStreamAsync(image.StandartResolutionURL))
               {
                    await contentStream.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
               }
           }

           file.Name    = "RandomZip";
           file.Content = archiveStream.ToArray();
       }

       return file;
}
```

Instead of using a `MemoryStream`, I've tried using a `FileStream` to test if my code is working and everything works just as expected, so I'm thinking something is wrong with my action and not my service.

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong here and what do I have to do to return a zip?

Comment: Can you try to set the position of the MemoryStream to 0 "archiveStream .Position = 0;" I always have this problem somehow and usually it is helping (90% of the time)

Comment: @Lenny32, did not work, unfortunately.

Comment: You probably need to dispose/close the archive before copying the memory stream. Disposing might write some postamble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After learning the fact that I cannot prompt the user to download a file with `POST` request I took a differect approach for this problem that worked perfectly for me and I want to share how I solved my issue.

Now I have 2 actions. My first action creates the zip in memory and returns the byte array, after that I keep the file in the cache so I don't have to save it on the server and retrieve it later, the actions looks like this:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateModel]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveCarousel([FromBody]CarouselViewModel model)
{
    File zip = await MediaService.ZipCarouselAsync(model.Images, ZipFolder);

    if(zip == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    CachingService.Set<File>(zip.Name, zip);
    return Ok(zip);
}
```

The second action responds to a `GET` call and gets the file from the cache and returns it for download.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult DownloadCarousel(string name)
{
    File zip = CachingService.Get<File>(name);

    if(zip == null) 
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=\"{zip.Name}.zip\"");
    return File(zip.Content, "application/zip");
}
```

And this is how my AJAX call that makes a POST request looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/Media/SaveCarousel",
    data: requestData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        window.location = "/Media/DownloadCarousel?name=" + data.name; 
    }, 
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

So basically my idea is that with the `POST` request I send the data I need to send and save the zip file on the cache and return the name of file. After having the name of the file I do `window.location` with the file's name on the success method of the AJAX to the action that gets the file from the cache and returns it to the user for download.

*This way, I don't have to save any given file on the server, which means I don't have to maintain the files myself aswell, which is something I was trying to achieve from the beginning.*

Comment: You would not need to save the file to disk. You could keep the previous server side code and do the `window.location` change as advised and get the same result without have to keep the files on the server. The overall issue stems from the fact that you were doing an ajax call. what you had on the server was still correct. But I get what it is you were trying to do. Nice work around.

Comment: Another idea is to not save to disk but to cache and once downloaded remove the archive.

Comment: Yes, I thought about using Cache. I will update my answer when I get it to work.

Comment: Check [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44521887/5233410) which address the drawback cited in your approach.

Answer (score 3):

It was unknown in the OP that the call was being made via AJAX.

Based on self provided answer by the OP. The following could be done to avoid having to save the archive to disk.

Instead of downloading and saving the file on POST. Store the necessary URLs for use later when generating the archive. Memory cache is an option.

Example storage abstraction

```
public interface IStorage {
    Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key);
    Task SetAsync<T>(string key, T item);
}
```

Any storage implementation should work once you can persist and then get access to the URLs after.

The service implementation can just hold on to the needed information.

```
private readonly IStorage cache;

public async Task<string> CacheCarouselAsync(IEnumerable<Image> images) {
    var token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    await cache.SetAsync(token, images.Select(image => image.StandartResolutionURL).ToList());
    return token;
}
```

When posting, the media service will trade the data for a token

```
[HttpPost, ValidateModel]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveCarousel([FromBody]CarouselViewModel model) {
    var token = await MediaService.CacheCarouselAsync(model.Images);
    // Generates /Media/DownloadCarousel?name={token}
    var url = Url.Action("DownloadCarousel","Media", new { name = token });
    var content = new { location = url };
    return Created(url, content);
}
```

the URL to get the archive will also be returned to be called client side.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/Media/SaveCarousel",
    data: requestData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        //data.location should hold the download path
        //setting window.location should now allow save prompt on GET
        window.location = data.location; 
    }, 
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

The GET action only needs to exchange the token for the generated zip file.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadCarousel(string name) {
    var zip = await MediaService.DownloadAndZipCarousel(name);
    var filename = $"{zip.Name}.zip";
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=\"{filename}\"");
    return File(zip.Content, "application/zip");
}
```

The token would be used by the service to get the URLs from storage, then download carousel and generate the archive.

```
public async Task<File> DownloadAndZipCarousel(string token) {
    //Get the model data from storage
    var images = await cache.GetAsync<IEnumerable<string>>(token);

    var client = CreateClient();
    var file = new File();
    var random = new Random();

    using (var archiveStream = new MemoryStream()) {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(archiveStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false)) {
            foreach (var uri in images) {
                var imagename = $"Instagram{random.Next()}.jpg";
                var archiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry(imagename, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                using (var entryStream = archiveEntry.Open()) {
                    using (var contentStream = await client.GetStreamAsync(uri)) {
                        await contentStream.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        file.Name = "RandomZip"; //TODO: derive a better naming system
        file.Content = archiveStream.ToArray();
    }

    return file;
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same result, unfortunately.

Comment: @KerimEmurla, And that is also with resetting the stream to position to 0 as suggested in the comments. I can also attest to that working for me in the past as well. But then again you said it works when using file stream. I'll do some more digging.

Comment: I set the archiveStream's Position to 0 and it didn't change anything. Setting the entryStream's Position to 0 is not possible since that Stream does not support seeking.

Comment: @KerimEmurla, seriously, I have that in production code and have no issues with setting the position of the entry stream.

Comment: I'm getting this: NotSupportedException: This stream from ZipArchiveEntry does not support seeking.

Comment: Change the `leaveOpen` flag to `false` when creating the archive. I usually have that as false. Other than that what you have is basically exactly how I zip of resources to be downloaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146537/discussion-between-kerim-emurla-and-nkosi).

Answer (score 2):

Move your `file.Name` and `file.Content` lines outside of the `using` block for `ZipArchive`:

```
public async Task<Models.Models.File> DownloadAndZipCarousel(IEnumerable<Image> images, string baseServerPath) {
  ...
  using (var archiveStream = new MemoryStream()) {
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(archiveStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false)) {
      ...
    }
    file.Name    = "RandomZip";
    file.Content = archiveStream.ToArray();
  }
  return file;
}
```

`ZipArchive` in particular needs to write out the zip entries during its disposal *before* you grab the content array.

Comment: I tried that, I'm still not getting a prompt for download in the browser.

Comment: @KerimEmurla: Is this an AJAX call?

Comment: Yes, it's an AJAX call.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't invoke a browser prompt as the result of an AJAX call. You'd need to set `window.location` or something like that.

Comment: You are absolutely correct and after learning this fact I took a completely differect approach for this problem and it al worked perfectly. Will post how I get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
file.Content = archiveStream.ToArray();
```

Should be:

```
archive.Dispose();
file.Content = archiveStream.ToArray();
```

Or, change your `using` statements so `archiveStream.ToArray()` is called after `archive` is disposed but before `archiveStream` is, too.

> ## [ZipArchive.Dispose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158289(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> **Remarks**
>
> This method finishes writing the archive...

Comment: I would also remove `Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition"...` because `File(...` should do that for you.

Answer (score -1):

From Mike Brind's blog: [link](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/306/working-with-zip-files-in-asp-net-mvc)

you can simplify the code as below:

```
[HttpPost]
public FileResult Download(List files)
{
    var archive = Server.MapPath("~/archive.zip");
    var temp = Server.MapPath("~/temp");
```

`// clear any existing archive
if (System.IO.File.Exists(archive))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(archive);
}
// empty the temp folder
Directory.EnumerateFiles(temp).ToList().ForEach(f => System.IO.File.Delete(f));

// copy the selected files to the temp folder
files.ForEach(f => System.IO.File.Copy(f, Path.Combine(temp, Path.GetFileName(f))));

// create a new archive
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(temp, archive);

return File(archive, "application/zip", "archive.zip");}`

Comment: If i'm not mistaken this example works with creating files on the server, which is something i'm trying to avoid. I'm creating the archive on memory and returning the byte array.

Comment: Maybe so, but the code is also self maintaining, in that it will only generate one zip file at a time...that being said, this could cause problems if several people try and hit the page to generate a zip file at the same time...